# Round arbitrary-length floats to n digits

Tags: c++, rounding, arbitrary-precision

I have already read most of the SO questions related to "rounding to *n* digits". I believe that this question is separate because it is more related to the rounding of arbitrary-length floats.

```
0.56714329040978387299996866221035554975381578718651250813513107922304579308668456669321944696175229455773495728285284421635951688
```

The number above is an example of the types of numbers I am working with.

I understand how to round a number in C++, it is fairly simple. However, I do not understand how I can round arbitrarily-long numbers to *n* digits.

For example, I may have a number that is 192 digits long that I need to round to 84 digits, or a number that is 1831 digits that I need to round to 293 digits. How can this be done using one function (or similar)?

Pseudocode for clarity, but I am actually using Boost multi-precision [cpp_dec_float](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html) for arbitrary-precision floats instead of standard floats:

```
float round(float num, int digits){
    //returns num rounded to n digits
}
```

---

Another problem that I have come across is when trying to round very long floats to a small number of digits.

For example, if I have a number that is 1000 digits long, and I want to round it to *n* digits, I have to do something like `floor(num * 10^1000)/10^1000)`. This doesn't work because 10^1000 is extremely large. A solution to this would be doing the multiplication and division multiple times with smaller exponents.

Comment: Just making sure I'll get the question right. Which of the two: round to digit count (relative precision) or 'round to unit' (absolute precision). E.g. `round(0.253e+5,2digits)==0.25e+5` (relative) vs `round(0.253e+5, 100units)==0.253e+5)`?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I am talking more along the lines of `0.0236` rounded to 3 digits returns `0.024` if that's what you're talking about?

Comment: "I am actually using Boost multiprecision for arbitrary-precision floats" - You're going to have to be more specific than that.

Comment: There you have it: `round(x, precision_unit)=trunc(x/precision_unit+0.5)*precision_unit;` - code in my answer

Comment: Your `0.5671432...` is **not** an arbitrary length float. It's a **text representation** of a value, and it will be **converted** to a floating-point value by the compiler. Floating-point values on every system I know of do **not** support 192 digits of precision, much less 1000 (typically, `double` can hold about 16 digits). Once you get beyond the precision of the floating-point value, any digits you display are essentially nonsense. So whatever you want to do with all those digits you'll have to do on the text representation, not on floating-point types.

Comment: @PeteBecker The definition of arbitrary: "based on random choice or personal whim". I am using it in that sense, and partially in the computational and mathematical sense. I do not know the specifics of how the Boost multiprecision library works.

Comment: @Anonymous - my apologies; I overlooked your mention of Boost multi precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited - better solution]

Doing the rounding can go based on:

```
round(x, precision_unit)=trunc(x/precision_unit+0.5)*precision_unit;
```

Something like:

```
  using namespace boost::multiprecision;

  const uint lower_prec_digits=28;

  typedef number<cpp_dec_float<100>> higher_prec;
  typedef number<cpp_dec_float<lower_prec_digits>> lower_prec;

  const higher_prec eps_div=
      std::numeric_limits<
          number<cpp_dec_float<lower_prec_digits+1>>
      >::epsilon()
  ;

  higher_prec pi(
    "3.1415926535"
      "8979323846"
      "2643383279"
      "5028841971"
      "6939937510"
      "5820974944"
      "5923078164"
      "0628620899"
      "8628034825"
      "3421170679"
  );

  lower_prec round_pie=lower_prec(trunc(pi/eps_div+0.5)*eps_div);

  std::cout.precision(100);
  std::cout << round_pie << std::endl << pi << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
3.1415926535897932384626433833
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068
```

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.